# Plot slope and intercept of a model with log and percentage transformations

Tags: r, ggplot2, intercept

This is the structure of my data

```
 > dput(test)
structure(list(MAT = c(4.9, 4.9, 15.5, 14.1, 14.1, 14.1, 11.5, 
11.5, 11.5, 17, 6.1, 2.7, 2.2, 2.2, 14.1, 14.1, 14.1, 9.5, 9.5, 
9.5, 9.5, 9.3, 8.3, 8.266666651, 8.266666651, 4.3, 4.3, 22.3, 
14.1, 14.1, 14.1, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 21.5, 21.5, 3.8, 3.8, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6), es = c(0.29603085763985, 0.421393627439682, 0.189653473156549, 
0.226685054608428, 0.291373762079697, 0.166533544378467, 0.250586529054368, 
0.146320008054403, 0.199565119644333, -0.0819047677231083, 0.15963948187092, 
-0.154628141843561, 0.201121044198443, 0.0867981239977565, 0.543870310978598, 
0.34547921143505, 0.37557241352574, -0.287318919407836, 0.207937483228907, 0.190143660810163, 0.276182673435993, 0.128596803172119, 0.454753165843559, 
0.399237234440439, 0.32075358541748, 0.362664873575803, -0.0865925288159671, 
0.51290512543514, 0.186308318839249, 0.147936083867325, 0.243792477087184, 
0.625169403695832, 0.110317782120045, 0.217836235313289, 0.171468156841181, 
0.50548821117127, 0.164418265301427, -0.00246305543239786, 0.325552346507191, 
0.381240606108843, 0.19337350462531, 0.0408803528990759, 0.321815078821239, 
0.307642815014319), var = c(0.00496277337027962, 0.0130962311273343, 
0.0180149624217804, 0.0134568083459063, 0.00139708925143695, 
0.000725862546533828, 0.00670831011660164, 0.0190783110089115, 
0.0641568910090007, 0.0121596544795352, 0.0653909966557582, 0.0514610437228611, 
0.0231592619167496, 0.0108989891148006, 0.0588577146414195, 0.0695760532112402, 
0.0744256820906048, 0.00997789089155498, 0.00928124381998638, 
0.0145009450673482, 0.00652956018299188, 0.0111886178917916, 
0.0265943757419349, 0.142676904340634, 0.110705177803624, 0.0576538348777718, 
0.0625171635976251, 0.0131652117394448, 0.00947904166717649, 
0.00813569411386797, 0.00444289889858652, 0.0673007030900184,0.00545169559098343, 0.240046081413733, 0.00561125010476281, 
    0.0185516235174018, 0.0179989506841957, 0.0496806959944248, 0.022478393723115, 
    0.0521209786580004, 0.282298667080106, 0.0151428845076692, 0.00992945920656693, 0.0145544965304081), MAP = c(810, 810, 1140, 1750, 1750, 1750, 
    1034, 1034, 1034, 720, 645, 645, 645, 645, 1000, 1000, 1000, 
    691, 691, 691, 691, 1134, 1750, 1326, 1326, 1140, 1140, 1310, 
    1750, 1750, 1750, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 
    1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750), CO2dif = c(162L, 162L, 190L, 165L, 
    165L, 165L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 150L, 335L, 335L, 335L, 335L, 348L, 
    348L, 348L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 220L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 
    350L, 350L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 320L, 320L, 
    360L, 360L, 345L, 345L, 350L, 348L, 348L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -44L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("MAT", "es", "var", "MAP", 
    "CO2dif"))
```

I run model selection using meta-analysis, and the best model to predict the effects size is:

```
library(metafor)

summary(rma(es, var, data=test ,control=list(stepadj=.5), mods= ~ 1 + log(MAT) + MAP + CO2dif + log(MAT):CO2dif, knha=TRUE))

Model Results:

                 estimate      se     tval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt            1.2556  0.3719   3.3758  0.0017   0.5033   2.0080   **
log(MAT)          -0.5740  0.1694  -3.3882  0.0016  -0.9167  -0.2313   **
MAP                0.0001  0.0001   2.5181  0.0160   0.0000   0.0003    *
CO2dif            -0.0042  0.0013  -3.2932  0.0021  -0.0067  -0.0016   **
log(MAT):CO2dif    0.0020  0.0005   3.7500  0.0006   0.0009   0.0031  ***
```

Now I want to plot `es` vs `MAT`, with an example with this model, assuming that `MAP`=1200 mm and `CO2dif`=350

```
MAPi <- 1200
CO2i <- 350
make_pct <- function(x) (exp(x) - 1) * 100

ggplot(test, aes(x = log(MAT), y = make_pct(es))) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = make_pct(1.2556 + 0.0001 * MAPi - 0.0042 * CO2i),
                  slope = make_pct(log(0.0020 * CO2i)) - make_pct(log(0.5740))) , 
                  color = "red", size=0.8) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic()
```

Effect size (`es`) is in `log` format, and I want percentage, so I transform it with the function `make_pct`. `MAT`, on the other hand, has to be log-transformed in the plot as indicated in the model output. Is the slope of the ggplot above correct with the log and percentage transformations? It seems to me that the slope is rather low. I am not very familiar with this type of plots and transformations, so any tips are welcome. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between `exp(es)-1` and the explanatory variable `log(MAT)` is not linear. 
For a given set of values of `MAP` and `CO2dif`, this relationship is of the form:
 `y = exp(es)-1 = k1*exp(k2*log(MAT))`.
This function can be plotted as follows:

```
library(metafor)
library(ggplot2)

modfit <- rma(es, var, data=test ,control=list(stepadj=.5), 
   mods= ~ 1 + MAP + log(MAT)*CO2dif, knha=TRUE)
pars <- coef(modfit)

MAPi <- 1200
CO2i <- 350

make_pct <- function(x) (exp(x) - 1) * 100

mod_fun <- function(MAP, MAT, CO2dif, pars) {
    y <- pars[1]+pars[2]*MAP+pars[3]*log(MAT)+
         pars[4]*CO2dif+pars[5]*log(MAT)*CO2dif
    make_pct(y)
}

test$ESpct <- mod_fun(MAPi, test$MAT, CO2i, coef(modfit))

ggplot(test, aes(x = log(MAT), y = make_pct(es))) +
  geom_line(aes(y=ESpct), color = "red", size=0.8) +
  geom_point() + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Marco, thanks for your answer, that certainly improves the fit and goes in the right direction. You said that the relationship exp(es)-1 and MAT is not linear. Do you think it might be also posible that the relationship between es and MAT is not linear either? Would it be posible to fit a non-linar model with `rma`? Would you say that's appropriate? Thanks

Comment: @fede_luppi (1) I said that the relationship between `exp(es)-1` and `log(MAT)` is nonlinear because your model used a linear relationship between `es` and `log(MAT)` (for fixed `CO2dif` and `Map`).  (2) You are already using a non linear model between  `es` and `MAT` (3) Yes, with `rma` you can fit nonlinear models of the class `y = a1*f1(x1)+a2*f2(x2)+...` where `f1`, `f2`, ... are nonlinear functions.

Comment: Could you please indicate in your answer i) how to fit a non-linear model of the form `y = a1*f1(x1)+a2*f2(x2)`using my data, and ii) how to determine whether the non-linear model is better than `modfit`above? Thanks